# Microsoft.Extensions.* version newer than runtime's

Tags: .net, .net-core

Imagine I have projects stuck with `net48`/`netcoreapp3.1` runtimes.

How safe/correct is it to add to them package references like  `Microsoft.Extensions.*` `Version="6.0.0"`?

Are these newer packages intended to be used with older runtimes as well?

Comment: What do the newer packages' target runtimes say?

Comment: It's incorrect. Unfortunately, the dependencies doesn't say this as @IanKemp suggests. Keep to versions in the 3.x range.

Comment: @IanKemp, almost all packages depend on a netstandard lower than 2.1 (except for EF Core, for instance.)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto did MSFT say anywhere that we're not supposed to use them with older runtimes?

Comment: If they did, I don't recall. I know from experience that using Microsoft.Extensions 5.x.x packages in .NET Core 3.1 applications fails - but this is anecdotal

Comment: Let's see if they can document it properly: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/27315